# Can you assign a reference expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

```
var x = 3;
var y = x + 3;
```

I want to know if it is possible in javascript to update automatically **y** according to the expression (**x+3**) whenever **x** is assigned a new value.

Comment: what should happen if you assign a value to `y`?

Comment: In my use case it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

With object `getters`, this could be achieved.

Refer [`getters and setters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

```js
var x = {
  x: 3
};
var y = {
  get y() {
    return x.x + 3;
  }
};

console.log(y.y);
x.x = 6;
console.log(y.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `window` object and add a getter for `y`.

```js
var x = 4;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'y', { get: function () { return x + 3; } });
document.write(y);
```